# Зависание приложения из-за потери связи с сервером

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

У меня есть функция, отправляющая запросы на сервер и принимающая его ответ:

```js
function send(send_id,url,data,cb_func){
        var xhr_data= new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr_data.open('post',url+'&global_code='+global_code, true);
        xhr_data.timeout = 1500;
        xhr_data.ontimeout = function(){
               console.log("Лимит ожидания был превышен!");
               setTimeout(send(send_id,url,data,cb_func), 200);
        }
        var params = "&param"+123;
        xhr_data.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr_data.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xhr_data.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
        xhr_data.onreadystatechange = function(){   
             if(!(this.readyState==4 && this.status==200 )) return; 
             cb_func && cb_func(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
            }
         xhr_data.send(params);
         };
```

Из-за того, что связь между сервером и клиентом непостоянна, возникает ситуация, когда программа ждет ответ на свой запрос, а он не приходит, так как связь потеряна. Это приводит к зависанию приложения. Я установила timeout, однако он не всегда срабатывает.

Как можно обработать такого рода ошибки?

Comment: Установка в конце функции таймаута var timer = setTimeout( function(){  xhr_data.abort();},60000); проблемы не решает совсем(((

Comment: в таком виде `setTimeout(send(send_id,url,data,cb_func), 200);` setTimeout бесполезен, его можно либо убрать либо переписать например так `setTimeout(function(){send(send_id,url,data,cb_func)},200);`

Answer (score 1):

У Вас проблема в том, что вы ожидаете только статус `200`. Поэтому, если статус не `200`, и запрос выполнен (допустим со статусом `500`), Вы не увидите результата. Попробуйте изменить `.onreadystatuschange` следующим образом:

```
xhr_data.onreadystatechange = function(){   
    if (this.readyState!==4) return;
    cb_func && cb_func(JSON.parse(this.responseText), this.status);   
}
```

Тогда, вторым аргументом в `cb_func` получите статус завершения запроса.

Есть еще вариант другой, когда первым аргументом передаете ошибку, если она есть, а вторым - результат (подход часто используется в node.js). Тогда, в случае `this.status===200`, можно вызвать `cb_func(null, JSON.parse(this.responseText))`, а в случае неудачи, к примеру `cb_func(new Error('Request error. Status: '+this.status))`.

П.С. ну и нужно проверить, что `cb_func` всегда передается, что это всегда функция, и что в ответе всегда валидный JSON, потому что иначе, в первом случае - просто ничего не выполнится, а в остальных - выбросится исключение.

---

**Upd:** Попробуйте, все-таки, в `cb_func` передавать просто `this.responseText`, а внутри `cb_func` парсить. Т.к. в случае срабатывания таймаута - `this.responseText` будет равен пустой строке, а при попытке вызвать `JSON.parse('')` Вы получите эксепшн.

Comment: подскажите, у меня вопрос по инструкции return, правильно ли я понимаю что если ответ от сервера не равен статусу 4, то return (т.е. вернуть ответ), и дальше ф-ция не будете отработана? (или return не останавливает выполнение цикла или ф-ции как например continue)

Comment: `this.readyState` это не сответ от сервера, это состояние запроса (1 - запрос открыт, 2 - приняты заголовки, 3 - получение ответа, 4 - запрос завершен, ответ получен), цикла там не будет, это callback функция, которая вызывается каждый раз, когда изменяется состояние запроса (либо браузер получил кусок тела ответа). `return` останавливает выполнение функции, именно это от него и требуется в данном случае (т.к. запрос не завершен, не стоит пытаться распарсить ответ).

Подробнее про `onreadystatechange` можно почитать на http://xmlhttprequest.ru/, или https://developer.mozilla.org/

Comment: спасибо)  у меня на самом деле периодически  обрывается связь с сервером и никакой ответ, соответственно не приходит. Я попробовала отслеживать статус в cb_func, но я туда просто не захожу и соответственно не могу ничего в ней обработать.

Comment: Если Вы пробовали отслеживать статус так, как в вопросе, что вы ничего не увидите, если сервер ответил каким-либо статусом отличным от 200. Сэмулировать обрыв связи вменяемо не получается, но даже заморозка виртуалки с http сервером не мешает вызову `onreadystatechande` с `this.readyState===4` по таймату. Но _статус_ не будет 200, соответственно в Вашем коде, функция cb_func не вызовется.

Comment: Я пробовала выносить статус в функцию, но она не запустилась, просто все оборвалось на if, причем в условие тоже ничего не пошло.  Может я просто неправильно все тестировала (сервер и клиент соединены друг с другом кабелем), запуская приложение и   останавливая соединение? В итоге наблюдалась такая картина, что после разрыва соединения запросы преспокойно пытались достучаться до сервера, а после того, как связь была восстановлена, приложение зависло на отправке запроса. Почему так происходит, Вы не могли бы предположить?

Comment: P.S. из условия статус был убран

Comment: Возможно, не успел отработать таймаут подключений. Браузер для ajax запросов позволяет открывать строго ограниченное количество запросов на один хост в среднем по больнице - 6 подключений. Откройте панель работы с веб-запросами в инструментах разработчика. Там видно и статусы запросов и сколько оги длились. Возможно, это поможет.

Comment: Мне кажется что дело не совсем в этом, тем более, что проблемы начинаются именно в тот момент когда появляется/исчезает соединение, а до этого запросы стабильно отправляются, даже если ответ не приходит. Вообще можно ли как-то застраховаться, что приложение адекватно среагирует на разрыв соединения в рандомный промежуток времени?

Comment: Строго говоря, приложение не должно зависеть от того, что какой-то запрос не прошел. "Застраховаться" - значит изначально рассчитывать на то, что сервер может быть не доступен в любой момент времени. Проверьте, все-таки, что происходит с веб-запросами (браузер предоставляет все инструменты для этого) и прочитайте, что в Upd ответа написано.

Comment: В том-то и дело, что ответ не приходит (смотрела в firebug)

Comment: ответ не приходит - это понятно, но в firefox, вполне срабатывает `onreadystatechange` по таймауту. `readyState` будет 4, статус - 0, тело ответа - `''`.